# Do I need to deal with concurrency?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, concurrency

I have an application where I am managing documents. I would like to ask you whether I need to deal with concurrency.

Lets say, I will have the method below (which is in the class with @Service and @Transactional) and more requests would come which would require to use this function. 
Will spring and database handle concurrency without synchronization? (my db is MySQL and JPA). So the first request to use this method will be executed, but another request will wait till the previous request will be done... so it would not happen that something would be overwritten in the database...

Thanks for help

```
public void updateSharing(long userId, long documentId, int approval) {
        Optional<Document> optionalDocument = documentRepository.findById(documentId);
        User user = userService.findUserById(userId);

        if(optionalDocument.isPresent()){
            Document document = optionalDocument.get();

            if(document.getDocumentState().getId() == 2){
                documentRepository.updateSharing(userId, documentId, approval);

                if(approval == 0){
                    List<User> users = userService.getUsersForApprovingDocument(documentId);
                    Map<String, String> map = emailService.createMessage(2, user, document);

                    if(document.getUser().isActive()){
                        users.add(document.getUser());
                    }

                    setDocumentType(documentId, 3);

                    sendEmail(users, map.get("subject"), map.get("message"));

                } else if(isDocumentApproved(documentId)){
                    setDocumentType(documentId, 1);

                    List<User> users = userService.getUsersForApprovingDocument(documentId);
                    if(document.getUser().isActive()){
                        users.add(document.getUser());
                    }

                    Map<String, String> map = emailService.createMessage(5, user, document);
                    sendEmail(users, map.get("subject"), map.get("message"));
                }
            } else if(document.getDocumentState().getId() == 1){
                documentRepository.updateSharing(userId, documentId, approval);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to deal with concurrency in this situation.

For every request, the container creates a new Thread and each Thread has it's own stack.

Comment: And how does it work? How is it assured that requests will run in order?

Comment: Requests are on different Threads. Each Thread will have it's own connection to the database. What is your fear? Sorry if I didn't get it right